# how to check that the server side in socket is open from client side

Tags: android, c++, sockets, socket.io

I have an android application that connects to the server throw socket by entering the {IP,port number} then clicking the "connect" button.

My question is how can I know that the server is not running so when I press the connect button it displays a message "server is down" or "server is not running"?

The server written in C++ and the client is Android.

Comment: "throw socket" ? What is that? Inspect the exception you get.

Comment: i did not get an exception it is work fine and the client is connect but i just want to check before connect  and display message

Comment: Of course you cannot know other than trying to connect. And if you cannot connect then the wireless can be off, or internet is down. And many possibilities.

Comment: can i do this thing : when i press connect button for 3 seconds and the server is down then print message

Answer (score 1):

`connect()` will get an error if the server isn't running, and not get an error if it is.